# ANSWERED: Python: Creating Zipped folder of CSV files, get this message, PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

Tags: python, zip, permission-denied

I'm working on a project where I extract csv files from a zipped folder to the current working directory, do some work with them, and then I'd like to zip them at the end. Everything works fine, but I get stuck when I try to re-zip the folders.

Here's where I get stuck:

```
newzip = zipfile.ZipFile(os.getcwd(), 'w')

for filename in os.walk(os.getcwd()):

    for file in filename:
        if file.endswith('.csv'):
            newzip.write(proj)
```

In the newzip line, I get the permission denied message for the current working directory. Any idea what I'm missing here?

ANSWERED:  Comment from @CristiFati worked!

Comment: You're passing `os.getcwd()` which is a **dir** to `ZipFile`. Try passing it `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "file.zip")` instead.

Comment: [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) or [`Path.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) (Python 3.4+)